# XHR returning status 0 when even there's no cross-domain request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Look at the following code JQuery snippet:

```
var ahr = createXMLHTTPRequestObject();
var aurl = 'bootstrap/php/flashgetnewdl.php';
var avars = "sn=" + 1;
ahr.open("POST", aurl, true);
ahr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ahr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ahr.readyState == 4 && ahr.status == 200){
       var return_data = ahr.responseText;
       alert(return_data);
    }
}
ahr.send(avars);
```

For testing purposes, I have a very simple code in my `flashgetnewdl.php`:

```
<?php
$output = $_POST['sn'];
echo $output;
?>
```

Ideally, this should just alert "1" to the screen whichever way I look at it. But for whatever reason, it's not doing that. I checked the values for readyState and status and they are 4 and 0 respectively. Why is it returning a status 0? Both JQuery and PHP blocks are sitting on the same domain. Is there anything I am missing out?

Comment: Is this happening form an onsubmit handler? If the page is getting unloaded, you may get a status 0, because three call is aborted. But you after right, a status of 0 means the problem is client side

Comment: there is no jQuery - you're more likely to get an answer if you tagged it [tag:javascript], as that is pure javascript with absolutely no jquery